# What should I do if I meet a wild bear in the forest?

Tags: bears

What should I do if I meet a wild bear in the forest? Should I run; fight for my life; climb a tree; or do nothing?

Comment: You don't *meet* with Wild Bear, et al :)

Comment: Hi! Your question looks a lot like the one @WedaPashi suggested. Why don't you have a look at it and see if it answers your question. Also, there are other questions here with good information about bears. An easy way to find them is to press on the [tag:bears] tag Liam added to your question.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: Polite as always @Sue :)

Comment: There are lots on answers for this question on this site, (I know because I've answered many of them). I encountered the same bear *twice* two days ago, once while hiking a trail, the second time while paddling my canoe later in the day. I left it alone, and it left me alone. Most of the time, If a bear doesn't perceive you as a threat, it'll usually go about it's business and leave you be.